# What kind of rule for using (gerund+infinitive)?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

sentence:

> Keep me from **having to mingle** *(I have never seen such construction gerund+infinitive. The only two cases I know is I'm **used to doing**, I'm looking **forward to seeing** - we can treat it as an exception)*

question:

> What rule can I exert to explain this case?

Answer (score 2):

That is not the exception. Here the verb after the preposition - *from* - is *have*. And it's no exception to write *having* there. The verb *have* can take a *to*-infinitive clause to mean obligation, for example, *I have to do it*. And so it's grammatical to write *keep me from having to mingle*.

A few similar examples -

> I could walk no more than a few feet without having to pause to net an unfamiliar species.
>
> It will save you from having to pay your full deductible two-years in a row.
>
> They're really well-adjusted around this business and understanding the nature of having to take a battering.